# Refresh an ImageSource efficiently: BitmapImage vs DrawingImage

Tags: wpf, imagesource, system.windows.media

I have a WPF control with a `GeometryModel3D` with `DiffuseMaterial` using an `ImageBrush` with data bound `ImageSource`.

My goal is to display a "cross-section" while hovering the mouse, and for that I can already get the proper position on the object. The problem is: There is no "3D Line" in WPF.

I have made a test drawing the line in the image I use for `ImageSource` and the visual result is exactely what I want.

So I plan to do the following: generate the base image once, and then draw the appropriate line on it, setting the property used as `ImageSource`.

I have considered two approaches:

1. Have the bound ImageSource of type `BitmapImage`. Then I create a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` once with the blank texture (without the line), and then each time I want the line to change position, I recreate the `BitmapImage` drawing a line with `System.Drawing.Graphics`;
2. Have the bound ImageSource of type `DrawingGroup`. Then I create a `System.Windows.Media.ImageDrawing` once, and then each time I want the line to change position, I recreate the `DrawingGroup` by changing only the `GeometryDrawing` composed by one single line.

Is there any inherent advantage of one method over the other?

Comment: "I recreate the `BitmapImage` drawing a line with `System.Drawing.Graphics`". Here you seem to be confusing `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`.

Comment: @Clemens I draw the line over a (limited scope) `System.Drawing.Bitmap`, and THEN I create a new `BitmapImage` FROM the aforementioned `Bitmap`... But I am slowly discovering ways to replace `System.Drawing.Graphics` and its drawing commands by `GeometryDrawing`, which have better syntax, are more "wpf-like", and can be used directly as `ImageSource`. Thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 1):

I must admit that I've never actually tested the performance difference, but I know that the `Drawing` class enables a light-weight way to manipulate basic shapes and images. From the [`Drawing` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawing%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> Drawing objects are light-weight objects that enable you to add geometric shapes, images, text, and media to an application. Drawing objects are considered light-weight because they do not provide support for Layout, Input Overview, and focus. Because of their performance benefits, drawings are ideal for backgrounds and clip art. You also use drawings when programming at the Visual level.

Conversely, the `BitmapImage` class has all sorts of additional extra functionality and convenience features built into it, making it less light-weight than the `Drawing` class. From the [Imaging Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748873%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN:

> BitmapImage is a specialized BitmapSource that is optimized for Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML) loading and is an easy way to display images as the Source of an Image control.

Comment: Although this answer is more of a comment (since my question is also speculative more than objectively answerable), your points are interesting. More interesting because, by MSDN descriptions themselves, both alternatives seem to be adequate. I tend to prefer `DrawingVisual` because I can compose it with actual objects (Image and Line) instead of GDI+ drawing commands, but either one should produce the same visual result. Fortunately I'll have the chance to test both of them as soon as I return to work, and I plan to post some feedback. Thanks for your interest again!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up replacing the old GDI+ based "Graphics over Bitmap and then convert to BitmapImage"
by a very WPF/XAML friendly way of generating the image with a somewhat bulky but actually very straightforward way of stacking "layers" of `Drawing` objects, with elimination of A LOT of code-behind.

The line itself is a hard-coded one, with its `Geometry.Transform.Y` property being directly set by events in code-behind using the `alturaFatia` Name.

```
<DiffuseMaterial>
    <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
        <ImageBrush>
            <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                <DrawingImage>
                    <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                                <RectangleGeometry Rect="{Binding LimitesMapa}" />
                            </DrawingGroup.ClipGeometry>
                            <ImageDrawing x:Name="MapaAtivo"
                                ImageSource="{Binding MapaAtivo}" Rect="{Binding LimitesMapa}"/>
                            <GeometryDrawing>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Thickness="2" Brush="Blue"/>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>                                                              
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <LineGeometry>
                                        <LineGeometry.StartPoint>
                                            <Point X="-200" Y="0"/>
                                        </LineGeometry.StartPoint>
                                        <LineGeometry.EndPoint>
                                            <Point X="200" Y="0" />
                                        </LineGeometry.EndPoint>
                                        <LineGeometry.Transform>
                                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="alturaFatia" Y="-200" />
                                        </LineGeometry.Transform>
                                    </LineGeometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingImage.Drawing>
                </DrawingImage>
            </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        </ImageBrush>
    </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
</DiffuseMaterial>
```